# .equals() in java doesn't work?

Tags: java

`.equals()` in java dosent work? There is a problem with my program, for some reason in the `while` loop part it is always active even if the `String a = answer[r]`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class security {

static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String q1[] = {"mother midd name","Father name","your pit name","First school name"};
    String a[] = {"Zakia","Mohamed","Dog","Kaliop"};
    AskQ(q1,a);
}
public static void AskQ(String q[],String answers[]) {
    int r = (int) (Math.random() * q.length) + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        int c = 1;
        System.out.print("please enter your " + q[r] + "?");
        String a = sc.nextLine();
        do {
            c++;
            System.out.print("Wrong! try again:");
            a = sc.nextLine();
            if(c == 2){
                System.out.print("only one attempt lift! enter your pass:");
                a = sc.nextLine();
                c++;
            }
            if(c == 3){
                System.exit(0);
            }
            c++;
        } while (!a.equals(answers[r]));
        System.out.println("you are in");
        break;
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: Your image isn't posted. And what do you mean it doesn't work? Maybe post a code sample...

Comment: You really shouldnt post images of your code. Take the time to make an MCVE and then post, in code markdown, that code.

Comment: forgiveme, this is my first time to use stackOverflow

Comment: the image of the code is available now. can you please review where is the error. many thanks

Comment: You should copy and paste the code to the question instead of taking a screenshot.

Comment: you'll never achieve while condition because your code will always execute System.exit(0)

Comment: it is only exits when c = 3

Comment: Yes, but that will always happen no matter what the answers are.

Comment: @Adam can you explain what are you trying to achieve

Comment: sure. the basic idea of this programme is. the system will ask the user a question (q1[]). then it will comper the user answer with the a[] to check if it correct or not and that is the whole point of the while loop. once the count of attempt = 3 programme will exit. it workd fine but now  the String a != answers[r] even if they are equals it comes as they !=

Comment: Forgive me guys it is my first time to use this site

Comment: **Why** did you deface your question by deleting the code that was previously posted? I've rolled back your question to its prior state and ask that you please not deface it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I am seeing, your code first sets c equal to 1 in the for-loop, then asks for an answer to a question, then goes into the do-while loop. Inside of the do-while loop it increments c to 2, then takes in another answer to a question, then checks to see if c is equal to 2. Since c is equal to 2 it asks for an aswer to another question then it increments c to 3. Finally, it checks to see if c is equal to 3 (which it is) and exits the program.

I suggest using a while loop over a do-while loop since it looks like you want to check to see if the user entered in the correct answer BEFORE you do any checking and error-handling. If you use a do-while loop, you are doing the error handling before it ever even checks to see if the user entered in the correct answer.

More over, i'd suggest using your second if-statement as an else-if statement.